# oss-cad-suite not installed error when running "apio verify"

Tags: python, package, fpga

I'm currently running Windows 11 with Python 3.7.9 and trying to get apio version 0.8.3 to work. When I try to run `apio verify` in a valid folder with an apio.ini file (from `apio examples -d icestick\leds` example projectt, although the default apio.ini file doesn't work properly with apio version 0.8.3 so I had to manually rebuild to support different syntax).
I get the following error when trying to verify:

```
PS C:\Users\[user]\scripts\apio\icestick\leds> apio verify
(DEBUG) Profile path: C:\Users\[user]\.apio\profile.json
(DEBUG) Home_dir: C:\Users\[user]\.apio
Error: package 'oss-cad-suite' is not installed
Please run:
   apio install oss-cad-suite
Error: Package not installed
```

When I try to run `apio install oss-cad-suite` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\[user]\scripts\apio\icestick\leds> python --version
Python 3.7.9
PS C:\Users\[user]\scripts\apio\icestick\leds> apio --version
apio, version 0.8.3
PS C:\Users\[user]\scripts\apio\icestick\leds> apio install oss-cad-suite
(DEBUG) Profile path: C:\Users\[user]\.apio\profile.json
(DEBUG) Home_dir: C:\Users\[user]\.apio
File version.txt downloaded!
Version: 0.0.8
Installing oss-cad-suite package:
platform_download_url: https://github.com/FPGAwars/tools-oss-cad-suite/releases/download/v0.0.8/tools-oss-cad-suite-windows_x86-0.0.8.tar.gz
Warning: full platform does not match: windows_x86
         Trying OS name: windows
Error: Got an unrecognized status code '404' when downloaded https://github.com/FPGAwars/tools-oss-cad-suite/releases/download/v0.0.8/tools-oss-cad-suite-windows-0.0.8.tar.gz
```

I don't know much about how to manually install packages, but I tried downloading [tools-oss-cad-suite-windows_amd64-0.0.8.tar.gz](https://github.com/FPGAwars/tools-oss-cad-suite/releases/download/v0.0.8/tools-oss-cad-suite-windows_amd64-0.0.8.tar.gz) from https://github.com/FPGAwars/tools-oss-cad-suite/releases/v0.0.8/ and extracting into a "tools-oss-cad-suite" directory which I pasted into "C:\Users\[user]\.apio\packages". Running `apio verify` still didn't work so I tried changing the directory name to just "oss-cad-suite" then going in one level and changing line 2 in "package.json" from `"name":"tools-oss-cad-suite",` to `"name":"oss-cad-suite",` hoping maybe that would make it detect the library, but when I run `apio install --list` I still get:

```
Not installed packages:

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name        Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
oss-cad-suite YosysHQ/oss-cad-suite
```

and `apio verify` still returns the same issue.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm dense and somehow missed the whole `Warning: full platform does not match: windows_x86`. In case this helps anyone else who runs into the same issue:
I ran  `apio install -p windows_amd64 oss-cad-suite` and this solved the issue.